# Jetty does not want to listen on port 80

Tags: jetty

I want to change the default port the Jetty 9 is listening on from 8080 to 80. I've edited the jetty-http.xml file to look like this:

```
<Call name="addConnector">
<Arg>
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
    <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Arg name="factories">
      <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
        <Item>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
            <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
          </New>
        </Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>
    <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
    <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="80" /></Set>
    <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="http.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
  </New>
</Arg>
```

However, for some strange reason when I startup the server it still listens on 8080.

Comment: That is just the default in that file, maybe you are setting `jetty.port` somewhere? Grep for that in the relevant directories.

Comment: There are only two `jetty.port` occurrences in `/etc`. One of them is in `jetty-proxy.xml` and is set to 8888 (not relevant) and the other one is the one I set to 80 in `jetty-http.xml`.

Comment: I have it in "jetty.sh". Did you look there, too? It also seems to look at environment variable JETTY_PORT for it.

Comment: I've missed that one. But there are only in comments for `JETTY_ARGS` and are not used inside the script. Is it really that hard to change the default port of jetty? :/

Comment: you starting as root or using setuid?

Comment: Not sure what you asking about but I guess as root: `java -jar start.jar`.

Comment: If you are in a *NIX environment, you need root privileges to listen on ports lower than 1024. Maybe Jetty can't open port 80, so it defaults to 8080 or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have your XML defined, it will use any `jetty.port` property first, then if not found, use your hardcoded port 80.

Check your `${jetty.home}/start.ini` and also your `${jetty.home}/start.d/*` files for that property.

Or alternatively, run `$ java -jar start.jar --help` and see if it shows up as defined at the end of the output of that command)

```
$ java -jar start.jar --help

(...snip...)

  The current start.ini arguments are:

    OPTIONS=Server,websocket,resources,ext
    threads.min=10
    threads.max=200
    threads.timeout=60000
    jetty.dump.start=false
    jetty.dump.stop=false
    etc/jetty.xml
    OPTIONS=jmx
    etc/jetty-jmx.xml
    OPTIONS=jsp
    jetty.port=8080
    http.timeout=30000
    etc/jetty-http.xml
```

At this point you have 2 options.

1. Don't edit the XML file and simply configure the `start.ini` entry for `jetty.port`
2. Change the XML file entry to not look for the property.

```xml
<Set name="port">80</Set>
```

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for (notably 2., but it's a great overall)! Thanks.